# using the message in the firebase localized error swift

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, swift4

I am trying to fetch the message in the firebase Localized error (swift), does anyone know how to achieve this?

```
func handlelogout() {
    do{
        try Auth.auth().signOut()
    } catch let logoutError {
        print(logoutError.localizedDescription)
    }
    let loginContoller = LoginController()
    present(loginContoller, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

so instead of using `logoutError.localizedDescription` that brings back the entire log about the error as seen below, how can I print the particular error message such as `could not find the user email`

Current firebase response

[image]

Comment: Do you want to login or Signup or Signout ?

Comment: login but I get a similar message when there is a signup error as well

Comment: Try to login with already registered user. Kindly show your login and signup methods